# Python Dictionaries: making the key:value the key and appending new values

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, key-value

EDIT: My question has been getting a lot of follow up questions because on the surface, it doesn't appear to make any sense. For most people, dictionaries are an illogical way to solve this problem. I agree, and have been frustrated by my constraints (explained in the comments). In my scenario, the original KV pairs are going to be encoded as data to be read by another server using the ObjectID. This, however, must be fed into an encoding function as a dictionary. The order does not matter, but the KV pairs must be given a new unique value. The original KV pairs will end up as a new string key in this new dictionary with the ObjectID as a new unique value.

Keep in mind that I am using Python 2.7.

#### The Issue

**Note that this is a matter of presenting a dictionary (dictA), encoded by the ObjectID values, within the constraints of what I have been given**

I have a dictionary, say `dictA = {'a':'10', 'b':'20', 'c':'30'}`, and I have a list of `ObjectIdentifier('n')`, where `n` is a number. What is the best way to create `dictB` so that `dictB` is a new dictionary with the **key** equal to `dictA`'s **key:value** pair and the **value** equal to the corresponding `ObjectIdentifier('n')` in the list.

The new `dictB` should be:

`{"'a':'10'":ObjectIdentifier('n'), "'b':'20'":ObjectIdentifier('n+1'), "'c':'30'":ObjectIdentifier('n+2')}`

If that makes any sense.

Comment: `"'a':'10'"` as keys? Why not a more usable structure like a tuple? E.g. `('a', '10')`

Comment: Dictionaries are not ordered, but you expected output seems to make assumptions that there is an order. Can you clarify what ordering you expected?

Comment: I can't come up with a reason why you would want to do this?

Comment: It seems convoluted but in my particular scenario I need the key to print out as one "thing", because the value is encoding the key. (does that make any sense)

Comment: Is this primarily a presentation consideration? ie, the way the dict is printed?

Comment: @deversEatsALot It's quite easy to define a function that takes a `dict` and prints it however you like. So using something like `('a', '10')` will **not** do any harm.

Comment: I am taking results from a CSV and turning it into a dictionary, then I need to encode the individual KVs from the dictionary using that `ObjectIdentifier('n')`. Currently the solution I have to work with needs to be fed a dictionary with the `ObjectIdentifier('n')` as a value

Comment: @dawg yes, it's a presentation thing which is why it's not an elegant solution, but it's the only thing I can think of that will work within my tight constraints

Comment: That's still not a clear description as to *why*, or what the order of those identifiers should be.

Comment: Since your values are strings in the example, can you just concatenate the string of `ObjectIdentifier('n')` with the relevant values? I am sorry, but your question is not that clear...

Comment: @MartijnPieters the order does not matter in this case, sorry for being unclear. They just need to be uniquely encoded

Comment: @dawg I cannot concatenate it, the function needs to be fed a dictionary with `ObjectIdentifier()` as an independent value

Comment: @tgikal The first dictionary `dictA` in this case is the data being fed to another server. The keys are describing the data being sent. In my new dictionary `dictB` the KV pairs are paired with a new `ObjectIdentifier('n')` value to be fed into an encoding function.

Comment: Isn't it then `{"'{}':'{}'".format(k,v):ObjectIdentifier(k,v) for k,v in dictA.items()}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that dictionaries aren't ordered. So you say

```
dictA = {'a':'10', 'b':'20', 'c':'30'}
```

but as far as python knows it could be

```
dictA = {'c':'30', 'a':'10', 'b':'20'}
```

Because dictionaries don't have order.

You could create your dict like this:

```
result = {key: ObjectIdentifier(n+pos) for pos, key in enumerate(dictA.items())}
```

But there is no way to determine which key will fall in which position, because, as I said, dictionaries don't have order.

If you want alphabetic order, just use `sorted()`

```
result = {key: ObjectIdentifier(n+pos) 
    for pos, key in enumerate(sorted(dictA.items()))}
```

Comment: Not entirely true, I think 3.6 or 3.7 added insertion ordering: "Dictionaries preserve insertion order. Note that updating a key does not affect the order. Keys added after deletion are inserted at the end."
"Changed in version 3.7: Dictionary order is guaranteed to be insertion order. This behavior was implementation detail of CPython from 3.6."

Comment: @tgikal OP says in the question that they are using python 2 though

Comment: or 3.x, who knows.

Comment: I didn't clarify in my question, but it does not need to be ordered. Every old KV pair from the first dictionary needs to be given a unique ObjectIdentifier value, but the order is not meaningful as long as there are no duplicates

Comment: @deversEatsALot Then I guess my first answer is ok for you?

Comment: @nosklo I had to modify the (n+pos) to be (str(n+pos) because PyASN1 needs the ObjectID value to be a string, but other than that I thought your solution looked good until I started getting unhashable type: list errors.

Comment: @deversEatsALot that means your original dict has lists in the value, and lists can't be used as dict keys.

Comment: @nosklo Yeah I feel stupid now because there are lists, it's a CSV file that was converted to a dictionary. That said, do you know how I'd get around it? Here's an example of of one of my shortest real-world `dictA`'s: `{'dprt': ['__mv_dprt'], '80': ['']}`

Comment: You could remove the lists or join them as a string; `dictA = {k, ' '.join(v) for k, v in dictA.items()}` but - at this point you really have to step back and reconsider - don't you think it would feel better to generate your end result by putting the unique identifier as key? Instead of putting the values in the key?

Comment: I'll try that, also I tried converting the entire thing to a string, which leads to a more than 1 value to unpack error so I may take a look into alternative solutions. I'll post what I found when I figure it out. The frustrating thing is that the rest of the guy's code I'm working on hinges on the ObjectID as a value so we'll see. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @deversEatsALot `result = {str(key): ObjectIdentifier(str(n+pos)) for pos, key in enumerate(dictA.items())}` would convert the whole thing to a string, but it will be hard to convert back... I wouldn't recommend it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would want this

```
def ObjectIdentifier(n):
    print(n)
    return "ObjectIdentifier("+ str(n) + ")" 

dictA = {'a':'10', 'b':'20', 'c':'30'}

dictB = {}
for n, key in enumerate(sorted(dictA.keys())):
    dictB[key] = {dictA[key] : ObjectIdentifier(str(n))}
```

Output:

```
{'a': {'10': 'ObjectIdentifier(0)'}, 'b': {'20': 'ObjectIdentifier(1)'}, 'c': {'30': 'ObjectIdentifier(2)'}}
```